# Strange characters follow when ifstream reads characters into 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, char, ifstream

I'm working on a problem which asks me to read a .txt file containing a word puzzle into a 2D-array of type char and output the words found.
I'm having trouble reading in the puzzle. Here is the code I use now to read in the .txt file and print out the dimensions and the puzzle itself:

```
ifstream in("puzzle.txt");
string line;
if (in.fail())
{
    cout << "Failed to open puzzle." << endl;
    exit(1);
}

int nrows = 0;
int ncols = 0;
getline(in, line);
ncols = line.size();
++nrows;
while(getline(in, line))
    ++nrows;

in.close();
cout << nrows << ", " << (ncols+1)/2 << endl;

// putting puzzle into a vector of vectors(2D array)
char A[nrows][ncols];
int r = 0;
int c = 0;
char ch;
in.open("puzzle.txt");
while (in >> ch)
{
    A[r][c] = ch;
    if (++c >= ncols)
    {
        c = 0;
        ++r;
    }
}
A[r][c] = 0;

for (int r = 0; r < nrows; ++r)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < ncols; ++c)
        cout << A[r][c] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Right now with this code I have, it seems to have read in all the characters at first, but then strange characters follow.

The result looks like this with an 8x8 puzzle:

8, 8

r d z i t p m f t e k a n s t

d t i b b a r o o k e l a h w

a a c j i e p n d k s d e o e

m z i h z i y l a t x i s h h

e e l s   J ≡ o ` : ≡ o α J ≡

o ¿ ■ `   V Ω o

```
   h ²
```

`
             α J ≡ o Ç

```
  ╢ 5 ╛ s ] 6 @   α J ≡ o
```

The puzzle ends with "e e l s". I did not want the rest.

Another problem is that besides having strange characters this puzzle also was not printed according to the current dimension, which is only 8 characters per line.

I have read about solutions involving inserting the null character, but I'm still not quite sure how to do so with a 2D-array of characters.

Thanks!

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays, you can't do `char A[nrows][ncols];`. Why don't you just use an array of strings?

Comment: Even better, why not `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: Why are you printing `(ncols+1)/2`?

Comment: A person who truly wanted to debug this for themselves would have first verified that the characters being read are correct.  You could have simply written a loop that does a `cout` for each character read to verify if the issue is with the data, or with your general character reading routine.  This should have been done far before you got involved with the 2D array, and would have led to far less code for you to post if this was the issue.

Comment: A couple warnings about `char A[nrows][ncols];` This is not Standard C++. Hand this code to someone using, say, Visual Studio and it's not going to compile. if `nrows * ncols` is sufficiently large, you will run out of Automatic storage and the first you'll likely know about it is when the program goes berserk. A typical modern OS will give you one to ten megabytes of storage, but you may find your self with as little as a few kilobytes in some environments.

Comment: @Barmar because the last character in a line is not followed by a whitespace.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about whitespace between the characters in the file. You're not skipping them when you read the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ncols` variable doesn't get the value you want it to have. Because the `line.size()` returns the complete size of the array including separator character. Therefore the double dimensional array is filled with wrong number of columns and some of the last lines are left with the initial random characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're not skipping over the newline characters at the end of each line when you read in each character. You can use `cin.ignore()` to skip it.

```
for (int r = 0; r < nrows; ++r) {
    for (int c = 0; c < ncols; ++c) {
        cin >> A[r][c];
    }
    cin.ignore();
}
```